# Generate large HTML tags fast using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, dom

i am cloning instagram chat space. i have a huge data getting (around 20k - 30k texts) fetched from a server using fetchAPI at once in form of JSON.
The fetchapi loads the data and then i iterate through the json to load the data into the screen using vanilla javascript and html tags.

i first used for loop to load the page with html elements but i dont know why entire browser crashes all the time.

so then i used javascript setinterval() with a timegap of 1 millisecond to load the data so it works fine.

the probelm is the 1 millisec time of setinterval method reduces drastically after loading some html like around 1000 tags. it takes hours to load 10k tags. it might take days to load 30k tags.

the plan is to host the website and use it for something persnel .

is there anyway to load around 30k html tags in a parallel way or like load 1000 on one tab and next 1k on a new tab or load al of them together.
i am new to web development.

these are the html tags

```
<div class="msg_received_container"><img id="receiver-image" src="image.jpg"><span class="msg_received"> <p> THE TEXT FROM JSON </p></span></div>
```

**(i want to load atleast 30k of this tag)**

and also the CSS on another file.

Comment: depending on how you display 30k dom elements, use [intersection observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to load more, your prob find you can fit 10 to 50 on page then as you scroll down, load some more, there should be no reason to add them all at once if the user is not going to see them.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone so if it loads when i scrool down what happens to the other DOM elements on the upper part. like the elements which i viewed will they be like destroyed ? is there any other way to like load and display all of it with fluidity ? so like the user can scroll the page without loading.

Comment: no, they stay there, you could remove them but your need do some height changes to maintain the overall scroll bar height. I thought the problem was adding them efficiently? which you use lazyloading as mentioned. You dont mention what the api is returning or if it has paging, only that its returning all of them. What api are you using?

Comment: there is a simple example [here](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/intersectionobserver/)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i am using fetchAPI to retrieve json data which i uploaded on github. this json contains text messages loootss of text messages. i want to display that text messages on screen like we get from any social media chat system. so there are aroud 30k messages when i use for loop to iterate the chrome crashes so i used javascript setInterval() API to view each DOM with an interval of 500 millisec so that all DOMS gets time to load . but i dnt know why after some time it takes more than 500 milli sec to load one DOM ( the time interval is increasing exponentially ) this is the prblm

Comment: @LawrenceCherone what i mean is that if we use intersection api to load the data automatically when scrolling . will the older data vanish coz what if the user wants to scroll up again.   if it does not vanish then isnt it the same condition like load all data hence crashing the system